# How does speed bit video accelerator work?

Tags: optimization, networking, video

What type of optimizations does [speed bit video accelerator](http://www.videoaccelerator.com/) use.

Answer (score 0):

From the [help page](http://www.videoaccelerator.com/help/):

> **How it works**
>  Leveraging SpeedBit's unique technology, SpeedBit
>   Video Accelerator downloads movies and
>   music from multiple sources
>   simultaneously allowing for
>   significantly improved download speeds
>   and video playback.

So, looks like they open multiple http sessions and stitch the results together on the other end.  Similar to many download managers.